# Problem in Create Stack when trying to integrate AWS Lex on web-ui

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am trying to integrate my AWS Lex using [this amazons web ui](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot/) and I get an error (details below). Does anybody know what is the problem and how to fix it?

After clicking "create stack" I encountered this error on CodeBuildDeploy:

> Embedded stack
> arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:179546827253:stack/lex-web-ui-intro-CodeBuildDeploy-6FHZ0YDBOM42/e8f62610-8d83-11eb-8bb2-12235dab63f5
> was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to
> create: [S3CleanupLambdaRole, WebAppBucketOriginAccessIdentity,
> CodeBuildRole].

[image]

Comment: You need to look at that "embedded" stack to see why it failed.

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded"? sorry I am very new to AWS Lex. I was trying to look for "embedded" option/button/tab and couldn't find any.

Comment: I've never heard of an embedded stack but I assume it's more or less a nested stack. But the long and short of it is, the stack you're deploying has in turn tried to create another stack, and that other stack failed, which has in turn failed your "main" stack. The stack name is in your error message: "lex-web-ui-intro-CodeBuildDeploy-6FHZ0YDBOM42". So have a look at the events tab of that stack to see why that stack failed. If you don't see that stack, set the filter to Deleted stacks.

Comment: Does your user/account have sufficient privileges to create IAM roles?